# Apply function to cartesian product of numeric and function type

Tags: r, dataframe, cartesian-product

I have a function

```
eval_ = function(f, i) f(i)
```

for a list of functions, say

```
fns = list(function(x) x**2, function(y) -y)
```

and a vector of integers, say

```
is = 1:2
```

I would like to get `eval_` evaluated at *all* combinations of `fns` and `is`.

I tried the following:

```
cross = expand.grid(fns, is)
names(cross) = c("f", "i")
results = sapply(1:nrow(cross), function(i) do.call(eval_, cross[i,]))
```

This throws an error:

> Error in f(i) : could not find function "f"

I think that the underlying problem is, that `cross` is a data.frame and can not carry functions. Hence, it puts the function into a list and then carries a list (indeed, `class(cross[1,][[1]])` yields "list". My *ugly* hack is to change the third line to:

```
results = sapply(
    1:nrow(cross), 
    function(i) do.call(eval_, list(f = cross[i,1][[1]], i = cross[i,2]))
)

results
#[1]  1 -1  4 -2
```

This works, but it defeats the purpose of `do.call` and is *very* cumbersome.

Is there a nice solution for this kind of problem?

Note: I would like a solution that generalizes well to cases where the cross product is not only over two, but possibly an arbitrary amount of lists, e.g. functions that map R^n into R.

Edit:
For a more involved example, I think of the following:
`fns = list(mean, sum, median)`
`is1 = c(1, 2, 4, 9)`, ..., `isn = c(3,6,1,2)` and my goal is to evaluate the functions on the cartesian product spanned by is1, ..., isn, e.g. on the n-dimensional vector `c(4, ..., 6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapply()` for this:

```r
eval_ <- function(f, i) f(i)
fns <- list(function(x) x**2, function(y) -y)
is <- 1:2
cross <- expand.grid(fns = fns, is = is)
cross$result <- mapply(eval_, cross$fn, cross$is)
print(cross)
#>                  fns is result
#> 1 function (x) , x^2  1      1
#> 2  function (y) , -y  1     -1
#> 3 function (x) , x^2  2      4
#> 4  function (y) , -y  2     -2
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks very much like what I've been looking for. However, I don't see how I would need to adapt this such that it would work for functions that map R^n into R... Can you help with this? e.g. ```fns = list(mean, sum)``` and ```is = array(1:15, c(5,3))```where I would like to apply the functions to the *rows* of ```is```.

Comment: For me, the same code works, provided that, in addition to the definition of ```is```, I convert it to a list containing vectors, i.e. 
```is_ = NULL;
for(i in 1:nrow(is)) is_[[i]] = is[i, ];
is = is_
``` 
If I do not do this, ```R``` flattens the array and the shapes get out of control. If you have a better solution, let me know! :)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on the right track and the best way to generalise this to higher-dimensional inputs is to construct your `cross` data frame such that your function argument column is a list of n-dimensional vectors. By the way, you can use `is_ <- asplit(is, 1)` to split your array into a list of rows.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt for my "more involved example" with n = 2.

Let `X = expand.grid(c(1, 2, 4, 9), c(3,6,1,2))`.
The following pattern generalizes to higher dimensions:

```
nfns = length(fns)
nn = nrow(X)
res = array(0, c(nfns, nn))
for(i in 1:nfns){
    res[i,] = apply(X, MARGIN = 1, FUN = fns[[i]])
}
```

The shape of the margin of `X` (i.e. `nrow(X)`) must correspond to the shape of the slice `res[i,]` (i.e. `nn`). The function must map the complement of the margin of X (i.e. slices of the form `X[i,]`) to a scalar. Note that a function that is *not* scalar has components that *are* scalar, i.e. in a non-scalar case, we would loop over all components of the function.